# Heat equation with time-dependent transport term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, transport-equation

$\bullet$ I have the following heat equation with a time-periodic transport term:

$$\kappa u_{xx} - a \sin(\omega t)u_x = cu_t$$

I'm considering a 1D domain over $-l<x<l$.

I'd like to be able to solve this for simple boundary conditions such as $u(-l,t) = u_0 - \Delta u_0$ and  $u(l,t) = u_0 + \Delta u_0$ and $u(x,0)=0$, and if possible from there to be able to construct a solution for arbitrary time-dependent boundary conditions $u(-l,t) = f(t)$ and $u(l,t)=g(t)$.

$\bullet$ I already have general solutions to the PDE:

$$u_{\lambda} = A_\lambda e^{-\frac{\kappa}{c}\lambda^2 t} [\sin(D(t,\lambda))\cos(\lambda x)+\cos(D(t,\lambda))\sin(\lambda x) ]$$

$$u_{\lambda} = B_\lambda e^{-\frac{\kappa}{c}\lambda^2 t} [\sin(D(t,\lambda))\sin(\lambda x)-\cos(D(t,\lambda))\cos(\lambda x) ]$$

where $A_\lambda$, $B_\lambda$, $\lambda$ are arbitrary constants and

$$D(t,\lambda) = \frac{a\lambda}{c\omega}\cos(\omega t)$$

$\bullet$ Each of those satisfies the PDE. However, due to the presence of both $\sin(\lambda x)$ and $\cos(\lambda x)$ in each solution, constructing a series using e.g. $\lambda = (2n+1)\pi/2l$ doesn't seem to lead anywhere useful.

**Does anyone have any ideas how I could solve the boundary value problem,** even in the simplest case $u(-l,t) = u(l,t) = u_0$? Initial conditions are less important, as it is only the long-time behaviour which I am interested in.

$\bullet$ Incidentally, I know from numerical simulations that the long time solution is oscillatory in the case $u(-l,t) = u_0 - \Delta u_0$ and  $u(l,t) = u_0 + \Delta u_0$ with frequency components at multiples of $\omega$.

Thanks in advance! Any advice would be greatly appreciated!